# flutter - How to detect Device's Sound Preference, is in Silent or Vibrate Mode?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

so far I didn't find any library or packages that support to read the phone's sound preference. Because I want to detect, if the phone is in silent mode, then my apps should not play any sound. **Currently, even I set my phone to silent/vibrant mode, the sound still can be played**.

Any Idea?

Is this related to native thing?

Thank You

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @albertpeiro I'm sorry, I still not finding the solution as this project becomes abandoned - but my suggestion, you can go to native by part of the flutter plugin library or entirely by go to Android Platform.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the `volume` plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/volume

It has a get current volumne method

```
await Volume.getVol
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flutter you can't do it directly. you can make native functionality to flutter using plugins. [exist plugins](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=audio). It's not a big deal to create a plugin. [developing_plugin_packages](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages)